# Angular UI accordion with buttons in the header part

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the accordion directive from http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ and I need to have two buttons in the header part.

1. Add - Create exactly same accordion below the original.
2. Remove - Remove the accordion. (the first accordion can not be removed -
       disable the Remove button).

I am new to AngularJS and please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2fhGm320iJJdTQn4KHQL?p=preview).

You just need a add and remove function in your controller

```
  $scope.addGroup = function(idx, group, e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    var newGroup = angular.copy(group);
    newGroup.no = $scope.groups.length + 1;
    $scope.groups.splice(idx + 1, 0, newGroup);
  };

  $scope.removeGroup = function(idx, e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    $scope.groups.splice(idx, 1);
  };
```

and a `ng-repeat` for your html:

```
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <accordion-heading>
          {{ group.title }} ({{group.no}})
          <button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="addGroup($index, group, $event)">+</button>
          <button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="removeGroup($index, $event)" ng-show="$index">-</button>
      </accordion-heading>
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

Comment: Hi Bekos,  this is what i am looking for. You solved my problem. Thanks you

Comment: Amazing Thanks! I didn't know about the $event var so this was a great help!

Answer (score 1):

put just this e.originalEvent.cancelBubble=true;

```
  $scope.addGroup = function(idx, group, e) {
    if (e) {
      e.originalEvent.cancelBubble=true;
    }
    var newGroup = angular.copy(group);
    newGroup.no = $scope.groups.length + 1;
    $scope.groups.splice(idx + 1, 0, newGroup);
  };

  $scope.removeGroup = function(idx, e) {
    if (e) {
      e.originalEvent.cancelBubble=true;
    }

    $scope.groups.splice(idx, 1);
  };
```